# Can magnets boil water with no increase in temperature?

Tags: water, electromagnetic-radiation

In this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ua6brgZha-4&ab_channel=grain) an experiment is done with magnets and water. And at 7:14 they claim that the water boils, but with no increase in temperature. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, just lower the ambient pressure a lot. Nothing to do with magnets and I didn't watch the video, btw.

Comment: Actually, if water is at 100 °C, applying heat will not increase *water* temperature, magnets or not, and it will boil till all gone!

Comment: At 7:14 they claim that the water boils but the magnets stay cool. The claim is not that the water, the glass, or the aluminum under the glass stay cool. They don't stay cool. They reach the boiling temperature of water. Then the water boils.

Comment: Would be good if you included more details so we don't actually have to watch the video- describe the relevant points.

Answer (score 3):

In the included Czech text is said that rotating (and cold ) magnets are inducing electric eddy currents in the aluminium disk inserted in the vessel.

So the disk is heated up by Ohmic loses and warms up the water.